# Timezone or Time conflict

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I deployed a Rails App but I'm getting the times wrong on the created_at columns.

I go to rails console production and ran Time.now and I get the correct time.

I logged in to MySQL and ran SELECT NOW(); and I get the correct time.

But when a new record is created into the database I get that it's about 5am when it's really about 1am.

Anybody experience anything similar? How did you fix it?

Comment: Did you add time zone to your application.rb ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Ruby on Rails: Why do I get timezones munged when I write a time to the DB, then read it back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319527/ruby-on-rails-why-do-i-get-timezones-munged-when-i-write-a-time-to-the-db-then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have default time zone set in your application.

you can do it in your environment.rb (Rails 2) or application.rb (Rails 3) file, you can set the default timezone this way:

```
    config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

Reference: http://databasically.com/2010/10/22/what-time-is-it-or-handling-timezones-in-rails/